# Typescript cannot find imported type Action

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am working on my typescript + redux project and trying to import type Action from redux as below.

```
import { Action } from 'redux'
```

It shows an error which says,

> TS2305: Module '"../../../../../../Users/LOCAL_DIR/node_modules/redux/es/redux"' has no exported member 'Action'.

However, I see there's the type declaration in `redux/index.d.ts` and it works when I write like this,

```
import { Action } from 'redux/index.d.ts'
```

According to this example, https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#usage-with-redux-thunk, it seems to work with `import { Action } from 'redux'`, but not in my case. Is there any additional config for this?

I have already installed the versions in my environment.

- "redux": "^4.0.4"
- "@types/redux": "^3.6.0"

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015",
      "es5",
      "es6"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redux provides it's own type definitions, so you don't need to install them from Definitely Typed. If you uninstall `@types/redux`, TypeScript should use those provided by the `redux` package, and your import will work.

The `@types/redux` package has been [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/redux).